# JavaScript - Find an object among an array of objects, inside an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, filter

I'm using Vue, lodash, etc.

```
{
  "street": {
    "id": "1",
    "streetName": "test",
    "buildings": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "buildingName": "test"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have a setup similar to this. This is a singular object, I basically have an array of these.

All I get is a `building.id` value.

From it, I need to be able to find the building it belongs to, and there isn't any direct list of buildings for me to access.

**Currently**

I'm using a nested loop to loop through each site until I find the one that has a building with that id. I don't know if I'm doing it correctly, it doesn't feel correct.

```
for(var i = 0; i < streets.length; i++){
    for(var x = 0; x < streets[i].buildings.length;x++){
        if(streets[i].buildings[x].id == '2aec6bed-8cdd-4043-9041-3db4681c6d08'){   

        }
    }
}
```

Any tips? Thanks.

Comment: Add the code that you tried.

Comment: `a.filter(x => x.buildings.some(b => b.id === givenId))`

Comment: @abhishekkannojia I don't see how it's necessary, but I've added it nonetheless.

Comment: @georg I'd still need to loop through `sites` (as `x`) though. I'm wondering if I'm able to filter any site that has a building with the given ID.

Comment: @Anaconda It is necessary, SO is not a code writing service, asker should post their attempt to the problems, what have they tried, and what's not working, so that community can help you out, instead of just asking how to do XYZ.

Comment: @abhishekkannojia I didn't claim it was as such. Others understood me fine without needing that script. It's not required for something simple like this...you're not very helpful.

Comment: @RobG Of course. Streets is an array of `street`, which I've typed at the very top.

Comment: @Anaconda I didn't say that it's not understandable or your question is bad.  I just pointed out that it's helpful for others who answer and to the future readers and is appreciated, if you post your attempt.

Comment: @georg—your code should be `a.filter(x => x.street.buildings.some(b => b.id === givenId))` and it returns the whole street, not just the building.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to get all the buildings in all streets by a `buildingId`, this solves the problem:

```
streetsList.map(streetItem => streetItem.street.buildings.find(building => building.id === searchedBuildingId)).filter(v => v);
```

`.filter(v => v)` is for filtering out falsy values since we want a clean result here.

If there can be more than a single building in a street with the same `id`, then use `.some` instead of `.find` in the example.

Comment: Perfect. Works. Thanks :)

It's the `map` part that I was looking for, it seems.

Comment: You weren't. `.map` is a wrong answer here, you should use `filter`.

Comment: @georg well pointed out. using [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the return value is *A new array with each element being the result of the callback function.* while with [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the result value is *A new array with the elements that pass the test.*

Comment: @georg For what I needed, this is indeed what I was after, mister :D - it's working for me now, thanks all...

Comment: @Anaconda: it's up to you what you're going to use, but accepting wrong answers confuses people and hurts the community as a whole. You were given the correct answer, please accept that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `filter` and `some` methods, like this:

```
var result = streets.filter(function(s) {
  return s.street.buildings.some(function(b) {
    return b.id === searchedId;
  });
});
```

- Using `.some()` method will return `true` if any `building` of the iterated `buildings` has the `searchedId`.
- Using `.filter()` will filter the `streets` array to return only `street` object where the call of `some()` method on its `buildings` will return `true`, in other words which meets the condition of having an `id`equal to `searchedId`.

**Demo:**

```js
var streets = [{
  "street": {
    "id": "1",
    "streetName": "test",
    "buildings": [{
      "id": "1",
      "buildingName": "test"
    }]
  }
}, {
  "street": {
    "id": "1",
    "streetName": "test",
    "buildings": [{
      "id": '2aec6bed-8cdd-4043-9041-3db4681c6d08',
      "buildingName": "test"
    }]
  }
}];
var searchedId = '2aec6bed-8cdd-4043-9041-3db4681c6d08';

var result = streets.filter(function(s) {
  return s.street.buildings.some(function(b) {
    return b.id === searchedId;
  });
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This returns the entire *street* object, not just the *building* object.

Comment: And that's what he's looking for?!!

Comment: @chsdk—then why accept an answer that returns the building (and "*I need to be able to find the building*")?

Comment: @RobG I don't know why he'd accepted it, but he's saying *I'm using a nested loop to loop through each site **until I find the one** that has a building with that id* in his post.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you have a *streets* object that contains *street* objects, like:

```
var streets = [
  street :{ ...  },
  street :{ ...  },
  ...
];
```

So you need to step into each street and iterate over the buildings. A *for* loop should be fairly efficient since it can return as soon as it finds the building. I don't think any of the built-in looping methods will do that.

The code in the OP won't work, as `streets[i].buildings` must be `streets[i].streets.buildings` and `if(streets[i].buildings[x].id` must be `if(streets[i].street.buildings[x].id`.

Below is a working *for* loop version, there's also a version using recent Array methods which are very much slower even on a very small dataset. According to [jsperf](https://jsperf.com/loop-vs-filter-etc/1), the *for* loop version is about 100 times faster in Safari, 10 times faster in Firefox and 50 times faster in Chrome.

I also think the *for* loop code is much more readable and therefore maintainable.

```js
var streets = [{
      "street": {
        "id": "1",
        "streetName": "test",
        "buildings": [{
          "id": "1",
          "buildingName": "test"
        }, {
          "id": "2",
          "buildingName": "test"
        }]
      }
    }, {
      "street": {
        "id": "2",
        "streetName": "test",
        "buildings": [{
          "id": "3",
          "buildingName": "test"
        }]
      }
    }
];

function getBldById(data, id) {
  for (var i=0, iLen=streets.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    var street = streets[i].street;

    for (var j=0, jLen=street.buildings.length; j<jLen; j++) {
      if (street.buildings[j].id == id) {
        return street.buildings[j];
      }    
    }
  }
  return null;
}

console.log(getBldById(streets, '1'));

function getBldById2(data, id) {
  return data.map(streetObj => 
    streetObj.street.buildings.find(building => 
      building.id === id)
    ).filter(v => v)[0];
}

console.log(getBldById2(streets, '1'));
```

Answer (score -2):

You might be missing `street` property, right? 
I mean it should be: `streets[i].street.buildings[x].id`

Comment: No, no - I'm accessing the street object just fine, but I'm asking if using a nested loop like that is optimal, and if I can leverage some Vue/Lodash/ES6 feature to quickly and efficiently filter out the result.

Comment: @Anaconda—define "optimal". If the test is "quickly and efficiently" then you've lost since you had to come here when you already had a loop, and for larger data sets, a loop solution can end as soon as it finds the answer but none of the non-for loop answers here do that.

Comment: I didn't lose - an 'optimal' answer was provided by somebody ;) 
Thanks for the help.